# Oracle Membership Provider error - "Your account was not created"

Tags: asp.net, oracle, asp.net-membership

I originally posted this directly on the Oracle forums, however, I still haven´t received an answer and it´s very important to me and my project to get it out of the way as soon as possible. If anyone here could help me, it would be greatly appreciated!

I am having the following problem:

In an ASP.net application, I´ve set up the Oracle Providers. I´ve already imported the Oracle.web assembly, as well as the Oracle.Dataaccess assembly.

I´ve set up a custom Membership provider that looks as follows:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyOracleMembershipProvider">
<providers>
<add name="MyOracleMembershipProvider"
type="Oracle.Web.Security.OracleMembershipProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=2.112.2.0,         Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"
connectionStringName="OraMembershipConString"
applicationName="OracleMembershipTest"
enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
enablePasswordReset="true"
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
requiresUniqueEmail="false"
passwordFormat="Hashed"
maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="4"
minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
passwordAttemptWindow="8"/>
</providers>
</membership>
```

the connection string looks as follows:

```
<add name="OraMembershipConString" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=TCP)(host=ip_address)(port=1521)))(connect_data=(service_name=rdcdb)));PASSWORD=my_password;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=False;USER ID=ASPNET_DB_USER;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
```

In ASP.net configuration, I#ve already set up the custom provider in the Provider tab, for both membership and role. On the membership part it is set to "MyOracleMembershipProvider" as stated above. I´m able to go to the Security tab, and click on create user, but after typing in a user name, a password, and the other requirements, and click create user, I get the following:

"Your account was not created. Please try again."

This keeps happening and happening, and I can´t seem to find the problem.

I created the ASPNET_DB_USER account following this tutorial, granting the respective privileges:

http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10928_01/IntroInstallation.htm

and ran the Oracle Provider sql scripts on said schema on the remote server.

I´ve been at this for hours and can´t seem to be able to figure it out :S what could be wrong?

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the Oracle user, that you are using to connect, is missing some privileges in the database. (Check the [installation note](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10928_01/IntroInstallation.htm)

Oracle Providers for ASP.NET requires the following privileges:

- Change notification
- Create job
- Create procedure
- Create public synonym
- Create role
- Create session
- Create table
- Create view
- Drop public synonym
- Grant access to and allocate space in an Oracle tablespace

Errors that occur during the setup script execution may indicate that the user needs to be granted the above privileges. If this is the case, the database administrator must grant these privileges. The Oracle Session State Provider for ASP.NET requires the CREATE JOB privilege when Oracle Database 10g or later is the database.

Granting access to and allocation of space in tablespace is important. (That what's got me :))

Answer (score 0):

@Anonymous Your suggestion is usefully.
I run this command: grant dba to myuser,
and it's ok now.